# Identifying prefixes of regex matches

Tags: python, regex

I have a module which need to receive some data from a TCP socket, and I have a regular expression which can be used to validate the data I receive.

Now I am facing the problem of knowing when I have received all of the data, which I am waiting for. If the data I have already received does not match the regular expression, it can either mean that the peer has send me invalid data which I must reject or that I have not received all the data yet, and I must block on the socket to read more.

Changing the protocol is not an option because the sender is outside of my control.

Is there any way to find out whether a string is a valid prefix of a string matching a particular regular expression?

For example given the regular expression `(ab)*cd` I want to recognize the strings `aba` and `ababc` because they are both prefixes of `ababcd` and reject `abac` because it can never be extended into a match for the regular expression.

I know this is possible in principle, because any regular expression can be turned into a finite automaton and it is trivial to modify a finite automaton to recognize prefixes of matches. But I found no way of achieving this using regular expressions in Python.

Can this be done?

Comment: why don't you just make a search on say `re.search('^(ab)cd', 'ababcd')` ?

Comment: @Bulat That doesn't work. `aba` and `ababc` are both valid prefixes, but `re.search('^(ab)*cd', 'aba')` and `re.search('^(ab)*cd', 'ababc')` do not find any prefixes.

Comment: they are not for this regex, try `re.search('^(ab)*cd', 'ababcd')`. you need to change regex if you want it to work for `ababc`.

Comment: @Bulat Change the regex how? I don't want to know whether the string matches the regex. I want to know whether the string is a prefix of something, which matches.

Comment: replace `d` with `$` or `(.)?`in regex?

Comment: As an aside, Java does support this with hitEnd. Unfortunately, except for Perl which you can insert arbitrary code into regex, I don't know of any other engine which supports this feature.

Comment: @Bulat It still doesn't match all prefixes. `a`, `ab`, `aba`, `abab`, and `ababcd` don't match.

Comment: well I don't know you domain, but basically you would replace each letter from the end to the beginning in a loop and try each possible combination. that is not a universal solution. so 1. `^(ab)*cd` 2.  `^(ab)*c(.)?` 3. `^(ab)*(.)?(.)?` etc.

Comment: You want something like [Regex101's](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3bK9/1) debug feature: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I40JZ.png . On the left, click on "regex debugger", check "Disable internal engine optimizations", and click on the red line - "Match 1 - finished in 38 steps". Python has a regex debugger, but it looks like it's only for the pattern, not the match: http://ideone.com/AWibCK (I might have missed something here).

Answer (score 3):

The right search keyword is regular expression [partial matches](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20regex%20partial%20matches). You can find it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

From the doc:

```
>>> pattern = regex.compile(r'\d{4}')
>>> # Initially, nothing has been entered:
>>> print(pattern.fullmatch('', partial=True))
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 0), match='', partial=True>
>>> # An empty string is OK, but it's only a partial match.
>>> # The user enters a letter:
>>> print(pattern.fullmatch('a', partial=True))
None
>>> # It'll never match.
>>> # The user deletes that and enters a digit:
>>> print(pattern.fullmatch('1', partial=True))
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1', partial=True>
>>> # It matches this far, but it's only a partial match.
>>> # The user enters 2 more digits:
>>> print(pattern.fullmatch('123', partial=True))
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='123', partial=True>
>>> # It matches this far, but it's only a partial match.
```

Comment: Why do you mention Perl? I am using Python.

Comment: I terribly sorry - was confused by other comment. See the updated answer.

Comment: This is not working for me. `TypeError: 'partial' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Is partial matching a new feature in the  `regex` module? I am wondering if Ubuntu might have a too old version of the module to support this feature.

Comment: Looks like it is too old. Ubuntu uses version 0.1.20140216-1 and it appears [partial matches](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/commits/a23bbfa76a149d868bdd4ba6b3328d8648cd98c8) wasn't introduced until 2014-04-10.