# Get literal prefix of regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

Here is the problem:

There is a list of thousands of regular expressions. I need to get regular expression which matches to the given string. *Hopefully*, these regexes are mutually exclusive, so if several regexes are matching at the same time, I'm ok with returning *any* of them.

I assume that most of regular expressions starts with literal prefix e.g.:

"`some_literal_string(?:\?some_regular_part)?`" → "`some_literal_string`"

I'd like to try the following data structure to make the search fast:

```
regexes = [index=prefix_length:{key=prefix:{*prefixes}]
```

now, to find the prefix, I need to iterate `index` from `min(len(string), len(longest_prefix))` down to `0` and extract subset of regexes:

```
subset = regexes[i][string[0:i]]
```

Now I need to check each element for match and if pattern is found, return it, otherwise, continue with next `index`.

The question is: how to get literal prefix of a regular expression in the common case?

Comment: To clarify: Is `some_literal_string` a function, a string, or a function that returns a string value?

Comment: @jkdev it's a literal example, maybe too literal - pattern on the left side of arrow has literal part equal to `some_literal_string` which I put on the right side. both left and right parts are plain strings.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to extract the literal part (if any) at the beginning of a pattern (whatever the pattern)? *(i.e: all before the first regex special character or special sequence of characters)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte exactly! Since you've explained me why joining regular expressions is bad, I am thinking about a better approach

Comment: In JavaScript you can use `.toString()` to convert a regular expression to a string: `regexVariable = /this\sis\a\regex(p)?/; regexVariable.toString(); // "/this\sis\a\regex(p)?/"` Then you could parse that string. I'm not sure if there's a Python equivalent...

Comment: @jkdev I guess parsing this is is most interesting part

Comment: You could split on [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

Comment: @jkdev this is obviously not enough since `?` `*` make the previous character unrequired

Comment: So you're saying you only want the literal prefix if it is required...

Comment: @jkdev what is not required is not a literal part, is it?

Comment: How about this? [Identifying prefixes of regex matches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31804781/3345375)

Comment: @jkdev this is unrelevant

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why did you delete your answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the following regular expression:

```
(?:[^.^$*+?{\\[|(]|(?:\\(?:[^\dAbBdDsSwWZ]|0|[0-7]{3})))*(?![*?|]|{\d+(?:,\d*)?})
```

- It's needed to replace backslash+symbol with the symbol in matched string after search:

  `\$` → `$`
- It's needed to replace octal escapes:

  `\0100` → `@`

https://regex101.com/r/fF8aB9/2